# Can't get the "Facebook Subscribe" code to work

Tags: facebook, subscribe

The code I tried using can be displayed from the following url: http://www.thebrazilianlanguage.com/test/test.htm. I can get the Facebook Comments widget to work, but not the Subscribe button

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing the Subscribe button at a Facebook Page.

According to [The Subscribe Button Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/) the `href` param must point to a user profile:

> href - profile URL of the user to subscribe to. This must be a facebook.com profile URL.

Comment: Thanks Igy
I tried with my profile URL: https://www.facebook.com/danielb2012, but still getting a blank. I also tried viewing my profile with my URL, but, when I try to connect, I get the following error message:

This content is currently unavailable.


The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or you may not have permission to view this page.